# Android indefinate service

Tags: android, service

Hi all android experts there,

I have a design problem. I am building an application which let user track their favorite products for an online store. I am getting the list of the products from the online store's api. then let the user track the products by storing them in apps database.

Now my application should send an email to the user once their favorite products go on some particular value of discount.

How should i implement this. should i run a serivce , and in the service keeps on checking the  price of the saved products continuously ?will it be a good solution, as the serice have to constantly make http requests to the server and it will be too much resource consuming ,  or is there any better way to do it?

Appreciate any help..

Comment: The way I see it, the favorite product should be stored in the Store Database and once the products go on sale, simply send a push notification to the Apps.

Comment: i do not have that liberty . I have to store some product id of the favorite product on the device side and then constantly look for it. so everything has to be done from the client side.